# Need help for xsl:template

Tags: xml, xslt

I have this in my xml

```
<GROUP>
    <ELEM_1/>
    <ELEM_1/>
    <ELEM_1/>
    <ELEM_1/>
</GROUP>
<GROUP>
    <TAB>
        <LEFT>
            <ELEM_1/>
            <ELEM_1/>
            <ELEM_2/>
        </LEFT>
        <RIGHT>
            <ELEM_1/>
            <ELEM_2/>
            <ELEM_2/>
            <ELEM_1/>
        </RIGHT>
    </TAB>
</GROUP>
<GROUP>
    <ELEM_1/>
    <ELEM_1/>
    <ELEM_1/>
    <ELEM_1/>
</GROUP>
```

I have and xsl which transform this xml to display it.
I want that the node TAB is display like a table with two columns LEFT and RIGHT and with one row each that display a list with ELEM_1 and ELEM_2.
I have a `xsl:template` how display ELEM_1 and ELEM_2 how I want.

I have this `xsl:template` for the TAB that does what I want

```
<xsl:template match="TAB">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td><xsl:apply-templates select="LEFT"/></td>
            <td><xsl:apply-templates select="RIGHT"/></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</xsl:template>
```

But the `xsl:template`for RIGHT and LEFT doesn't work how I want

```
<xsl:template match="LEFT">
    <ul class="Group">
        <li class="TabTitle">Left title</li>
        <xsl:if test="ELEM_1">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="ELEM_1"/>
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:if test="ELEM_2">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="ELEM_2"/>
        </xsl:if>
    </ul>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="RIGHT">
    <ul class="Group">
        <li class="TabTitle">Right title</li>
            <xsl:if test="ELEM_1">
                <xsl:apply-templates select="ELEM_1"/>
            </xsl:if>
            <xsl:if test="ELEM_2">
                <xsl:apply-templates select="ELEM_2"/>
            </xsl:if>
    </ul>
</xsl:template>
```

How to do it right?
Thanks

Comment: Do you have any specific template for ELEM_1 or ELEM_2 ? And what is the expected results in the td ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not certain why your tests are failing. In the solution below, you don't need to test anyway, the beauty of XSLT being a declarative language. Here you go:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"  xmlns:php="http://php.net/xsl">

<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="/ROOT/GROUP/TAB" />
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="TAB">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="LEFT | RIGHT "/>
        </tr>
    </table>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="LEFT">
    <td>
     <ul class="Group">
            <li class="TabTitle">Left title</li>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="ELEM_1"/>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="ELEM_2"/>
       </ul>
   </td>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="RIGHT">
    <td>
         <ul class="Group">
                <li class="TabTitle">Right title</li>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="ELEM_1"/>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="ELEM_2"/>
        </ul>
    </td>
</xsl:template>

<!-- your elm templates -->
<xsl:template match="ELEM_1">
    <p>ELEM 1 OUTPUT</p>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="ELEM_2">
    <p>ELEM 2 OUTPUT</p>
</xsl:template>


</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Note: this preserves the ordering of your original examples ('1's first, then '2's)

Comment: It give the same result that I already have. 
It display all the element in a list but it put all the nodes `ELEM_1` then the `ELEM_2`. And I want that it display in the same order. For example in the element `RIGHT`, I want that it display `ELEM_1, ELEM_2, ELEM_2, ELEM_1` and not `ELEM_1, ELEM_1, ELEM_2, ELEM_2`

Comment: By applying to ELEM_1 then ELEM_2 separately, you are explicitly ordering them that way. To output them in the same order as the source data, just apply-templates without a select, like Vitaliy has above.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what example the result you going to achieve (probably enumerate ELEM_1, ELEM_2 nodes):

```
<xsl:template match="TAB">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td><xsl:apply-templates select="LEFT"/></td>
            <td><xsl:apply-templates select="RIGHT"/></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="LEFT">
  <ul class="Group">
    <li class="TabTitle">Left title</li>

    <xsl:apply-templates />

  </ul>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="RIGHT">
  <ul class="Group">
    <li class="TabTitle">Right title</li>

    <xsl:apply-templates />  
  </ul>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="LEFT/* | RIGHT/*">
    <!--Do something - copy Elem_1, Elem_2 element nodes for example -->
    <xsl:copy/>
</xsl:template>
```